# Unable to Convert String to Either JSONArray or JSONObject

Tags: android, arrays

I was not able to convert String to JSONArray or JSONObject. Here is the code below:

```
JSONArray entries = WebRequest.execute(request);
if(entries!=null){          
    try{
        String temp  = entries.getJSONObject(0).getString(WebRequest.CONTENT);    
        String s = temp.toString();
        JSONArray cont = new JSONArray(s);

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), cont.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch(Exception e){                
    }
}
```

Here is the String result :

"[{\ID_PROJECT\":528,\"NM_PROJECT\":\"TestProject\",,\"NM_TASK\":\"TestTask\"}]"

I was not able to get the toast when using this code.

Comment: are you getting any exception? first change catch(Exception e) to catch(JSONException je) then try to find out exception

Comment: Add Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); in your catch block or even easier System.out.println(e.toString()) and please post the output

Comment: Spring edited my post with Json data

Comment: Its a invalid json buddy. check in http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: So What is the solution now Spring?

Comment: If the json data is exactly what you have posted, then you need to consult your webservice people to provide a valid json data.

Comment: Even I was handling the webservice Spring

Comment: use this json string[{\"ID_PROJECT\":528,\"NM_PROJECT\":\"TestProject\",\"NM_TASK\":\"TestTask\"}]

Comment: this is right syntax of json{"data":[{"ID_PROJECT":528,"NM_PROJECT":"TestProject","NM_TASK":"TestTask"}]}

Answer (score 1):

This is json parsing of your json string

```
String OutputData = "";
JSONObject jsonResponse;

try {

      /****** Creates a new JSONObject with name/value mappings from the JSON string. ********/
      jsonResponse = new JSONObject("{\"data\":[{\"ID_PROJECT\":528,\"NM_PROJECT\":\"TestProject\",\"NM_TASK\":\"TestTask\"}]}");

      /***** Returns the value mapped by name if it exists and is a JSONArray. ***/
      /*******  Returns null otherwise.  *******/
      JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("data");

      /*********** Process each JSON Node ************/

      int lengthJsonArr = jsonMainNode.length();  

      for(int i=0; i < lengthJsonArr; i++) {
                    /****** Get Object for each JSON node.***********/
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                    /******* Fetch node values **********/
                    int project_id        = Integer.parseInt(jsonChildNode.optString("ID_PROJECT").toString());
                    String project_name   = jsonChildNode.optString("NM_PROJECT").toString();
                    String task_name = jsonChildNode.optString("NM_TASK").toString();


                    OutputData += "Node : \n\n     "+ project_id +" | "
                                                    + project_name +" | "
                                                    + task_name +" \n\n ";

      }

      /************ Show Output on screen/activity **********/
      output.setText( OutputData );

  } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
}
```